# Finding the height of a binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I wrote the following code for finding the height of the binary tree, this is wrong, its failing the test cases, but why it is wrong, how to prove logically that this is wrong?

**// WRONG CODE**

```
public static int height(Node root) {
          if(root != null){
            if(root.left != null && root.right != null){   
              return Math.max(height(root.left), height(root.right)) + 1;
            }else if(root.left != null){
               return height(root.left);  
            }else{
               return height(root.right);
            } 
          }
        return 0;  
    }
```

Whereas this following code is right!!

**//RIGHT WORKING CODE**

```
public static int height(Node root) {
    if(root != null){
        if(root.left != null || root.right != null){   
          return Math.max(height(root.left), height(root.right)) + 1;
        }
      }
    return 0;  
}
```

What is the big difference between the two codes that makes one of them right and other the wrong one?

For clarity the class code for the Node is added here.

```
class Node {
    Node left;
    Node right;
    int data;

    Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }
}
```

And this is the logic to insert a node into the binary tree.

```
public static Node insert(Node root, int data) {
    if(root == null) {
        return new Node(data);
    } else {
        Node cur;
        if(data <= root.data) {
            cur = insert(root.left, data);
            root.left = cur;
        } else {
            cur = insert(root.right, data);
            root.right = cur;
        }
        return root;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second and third cases (just a left node, or just a right node) you're not adding one to account for the node you're currently on.

By the way your code also has a potential bug, in that it's possible for both `left` and `right` to be `null`. Your `height` function can handle `null` so really none of this checking is necessary, except for the check on the first line of the `height` function itself. But if it's important to check for `null` in the second case, then you should check for `null` in the third case too.

Comment: if I am adding the 1 to if(root.left != null) and if(root.right != null), then will that make the first wrong code equivalent to the second one? Even then I am getting wrong answer. Please kindly write the code.

Comment: Equivalent in effect but not in operation. Let's say you have a node where `left` is a subtree of height 3 while `right` is `null`. In the second "working" version you recursively call `height` on both `left` and `right` because `left` is not null. The call with `left` returns 3 and the call with `right` returns zero. Max is 3, add 1 gives 4. In the first version you only call `height` recursively with `left` and get the same answer 3, skipping the call to `height` with `right`, which you know will return 0. You still have to add 1 to 3 to get the height of the tree at `root`.

Comment: The entire implementation of `height` can be just: `if (root != null) ? Math.max(height(root.left), height(root.right)) + 1 : 0`.